# load Repeater DB Data on page scroll

Tags: jquery, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am working smiler like pinterest.com.

I am using Visual studio 2010 with repeater,MS SQL DB and masonry jquery plugin in my project.

Every thing is working fine, but the big problem is **repeater is loading all data at once, i want it load first 10 pics records from DB and when user scroll page to end then load next 10 pics records and so on** .. like infinet page same like Facebook and pinterest.com.
I used SqlDataSource component to get data from DB.

Help me to fix this issue, Any suggestion or idea or link is welcome.

Live page demo is here [www.bhinderblink.com](http://www.bhinderblink.com)

Page header coding....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#container').masonry({ // options 
            itemSelector: '.item', columnWidth: 240,
            isAnimated: true,
            animationOptions: {
                duration: 750,
                easing: 'linear',
                queue: false
            }
        });
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            alert("end of the page");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Page Body start.....

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="topBanner">
</div>

<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="item">
                <a id="a" href="#">
                    <asp:Image ID="myimage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#"~/" + Eval("pic_path") + Eval("pic_name") + ".jpg" %>' />
            </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT pic_name, pic_path FROM pic_info"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</form>
```

Comment: There are [many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+paging+results&submit=search) on this site already about paging through query results, do they help you? If not, why not? What detailed problem do you have?

Comment: Thank you for replying. i try to find all over this website, but there is no question related to **control flow of REPEATER data**. Because "repeater control" load all data at once, but i need to load first 10 records in repeater and when user reach to end of the page with scrolling, then repeater load/append next 10 records. The best example for this is pinterest.com and facbook wall.

Comment: I know nothing about `Repeater` controls, but I can see there are [lots of questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=paging+repeater+control) about using them for paging. Again, if you can explain in detail why none of the existing answers work for you then you may get a better answer.

Comment: I already told you i try to find but there is no question related to my question, ok then please help me to find a question related to this "repeater paging with SqlDataSource1 VB2010". i knew there are many questions related to repeater but there are no question related to "how repeater paging works with SqlDataSource1 in VB2010". Pondlife u can try to find for me, i ll appreciate it. :)